# The Atom Riddles #1

Tags: riddle, wordplay, science

You wake up in a lab room, with papers, test tubes, computers, not understanding how you got there. A scientist is across the room.

"Welcome to my secret lab", he says. "To get out, you must complete the Atom Riddles. "

"I've been puzzled too much! Can you make it quick? And I don't like science that much", you say rudely.

"Fine. I'll give you the rules". He sighs.

## The Atom Riddles

Each riddle gets progressively harder than the previous one. There are a simple set of rules: There are clues in each sentence you read. You have to find the correct atomic element that matches the clues.

The scientist walks out of the room, leaving a periodic table and a set of papers behind. You read the first one:

> My name says that I make a familiar element. 
> They call us Mickey's ears there 
> If you put me in a flame test, 
> POP! 
> I am the smallest of a group of things, too!

> What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

> **Hydrogen** (H)

---

My name says that I make a familiar element.

> H<sub>2</sub>O is water, a familiar element with hydrogen in it.
>
> The word 'Hydrogen' is greek for 'Water creator' (Hydro - water, + gen - creator)

They call us Mickey's ears there

> A H<sub>2</sub>O molecule [looks like Mickey Mouse ears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PcdD.png)

If you put me in a flame test,
POP!

> Hydrogen makes a loud pop sound when put in a Bunsen burner

I am the smallest of a group of things, too!

> Hydrogen is the smallest element.

So, you are:

> Hydrogen!

Comment: Yes, it is! Good job!

Comment: You also forgot that rot13(Ulqebtra pna or fcyvg hc vagb "Ulqeb" naq "Tra". Vs jr genafyngr vg vagb (jnf vg Terrx be Yngva? ) Jr trg "Jngre-sbezvat".)

Comment: @zixuan oh wow I never knew that! I'll add that in, you learn something new everyday :P