# The Atom Riddles #2

Tags: riddle, wordplay, science

Previous level, introduction: [The Atom Riddles #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105509/the-atom-riddles-1)

**Rules**:

- Again, you are trapped in a room by a mad scientist.
- There are clues in each sentence you read. You have to find the correct atomic element that matches the clues.

Here is the real riddle.

> I am an tragic element to fuse in stars. 
> Very tough I am. 
> Yet magnets can grab me.

> What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably

> *iron*

which

> is the endpoint of ordinary fusion processes in stars, because fusing it further isn't energetically favourable -- to get heavier elements you need supernovas and the like; is indeed pretty tough; and is ferromagnetic and attracted to magnets.